# Spring MVC form validation Date field

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc

I have a form field that should be converted to a Date object, as follows:

```
<form:input path="date" />
```

And I have requirement to make validation in following way:

1. If user leaves this field es empty. I need to set some default date.
2. If User enetered in unacceptable format, I need to present an error.

The problem is that I can meet either 1st or 2nd requirement.

1. I can register **PropertyEditor** and in case date is unacceptable set null, and in case this field null set some default date. But with this approach I can't meet 2nd requirement because if I convert it to null I won't have ability to register 2nd error to user.
2. I can set  **@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")**  annotation and provide appropriate typeMismatch error but it still return this error when user leaves empty value in this field.

Is any good solution to such problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you have only @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy") and it is on getter/setter ? Because I do use that annotation and it accepts empty field (Spring 3.2.4)

Comment: Is this field passed as "" ?

Comment: Use a date picker, and force the formatting

Comment: In my application, I managed to spy the content of the request. The field is passed as `name=&` that is as an empty value and I get it in my object as null (the full object is annotated as `@ModelAttribute`)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this if you'll move from Spring MVC validators to Hibernate. It's not a big deal because Hibernate validators work well with Spring Validator interface (also you may be interested in SmartValidator intreface which supports groups).

After that you can specify
`@NotNull`
annotation on the date field.

In properties file just add
`NotNull.[formName].[dateField]`=This message will be displayed if no date sent
`typeMismatch.[formName].[dateField]`=This message will be displayed if spring was not able to convert input to date object (format validation  error)

For format check you can use `CustomDateEditor`.

With this solution you will get expected validation error messages in each case you've specified.

Answer (score 1):

When I have to face such a problem, I reverse the logic. I do not set a default value to an empty field, but I pre-load the field with the default value in the render part of the operation. So I can safely valid with just `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")` because an empty field suppose that the user indendly removed the default value which is an error.

So IMHO you should set your default values in the GET part of you controller for that form and stick to a simple `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")` annotation.

I have an application using a `@ModelAttribute` annotated object containing a date field.
In the object class, the date field is annotated on getter and setter with `DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")`. And Spring (3.2.4) accept an empty value for the date field which simply sets it to null. So you should use `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")` and still be able to accept null values.

Comment: Yes, you can prefill this value in the form but user can drop this value and send such form. And After that you'll face with such problem as I described. Please let me know if I am misunderstood your answer

Comment: If I prefill the value and the user drops it, I understand he does not want of this default value and he preferes and empty value. So I do not want to silently persist the default value in database, and I prefer send an error saying the field cannot be empty (and I propose again the default value). It would be different if you said the date must be null if the field is not empty. Anyway I know I've allready been accepting null values in fields annotated with `@DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy")`. I'll update my answer when I can found how.

Comment: For me both cases are ok:
1. In case user dropped everything return: this field can't be empty;2. In case invalid input: you date format ..., But it looks like Spring everytime will return incorrect format.

Comment: @user1459144 I've updated my answer with a precision on empty field management.