# How to @Valid a Date only if users insert it (Spring MVC + Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, date, spring-mvc, annotations

I have this POJO, used as `modelAttribute` in a form, that allow users to search record on the DB:

```
public class FatherSearch extends Father{
    ...
    @Past   
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date dataDiNascita; 
    ...
}
```

I have to check if the date inserted by the users is a `@Past` date; I should check the date just if users insert it.

The problem is that since dataDiNascita is a `Date` it can't be null and when users submit the form without filling the date field, they get the error `typeMismatch`.

Here is the controller where I get the error:

```
@RequestMapping("/admin/fatherSearchSent")
public String fatherSearchSent(..., @Valid FatherSearch fatherSearch,...){
}
```

I have to allow users to decide whether insert a date in the search form or not, so I need a way to handle the case in which users don't insert any date.

Thank you

Comment: Why dataDiNascita can't be null?

Comment: Because when I valid the modelAttribute I get the typeMismatch error on the date field. I edited my post, maybe now is clearer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053139/spring-mvc-form-validation-date-field

Comment: Spring doesn't validate null values, if a value is null and the field doesn't have a @notnull validation Spring will not validate the field.