# How to validate a date field to allow only current dates or future dates in spring java

Tags: java, spring, validation

I was asked to add a validation to the "date field". Only the present or a future date is allowed.Otherwise it shows an error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC form validation Date field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053139/spring-mvc-form-validation-date-field)

Comment: Are you using datepicker??

Comment: You may find this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482252/validation-of-a-date-with-hibernate

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with javascript. If you want to do this in frontend.Below is the answer

To make any past dates unselectable, you first have to find the instantiation of the datepicker, and set the minDate setting to zero.

```
$('element').datepicker({
    minDate : 0
});
```

Comment: <p:calendar id="popup44" title="Order Date"
               value="#{pmBean.pfmworkorderhead.docdate}"
               pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />

Comment: I'm using this @Ravi Kumar.